# Project downloaded from Github setup errors

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, download, syntax-error

I apologize ahead of time if these questions are very dumb. I'm pretty new to sourcing python code from github. The link I am attempting to use is a study from link: https://github.com/malllabiisc/ConfGCN. So far, what I have tried is downloading the code as a zip. Then, I followed the instructions from Github and downloaded Ubuntu to run the shell file setup.sh. However, I am running into errors as after running `sudo bash setup.sh` in Ubuntu, it gives me this error:

`Install python dependencies`

`setup.sh: line 11: pip: command not found`

I have checked out the respective files this references. It calls for:

`echo "Install python dependencies"`

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

Inside the requirements.txt file it has a variety of python packages I have already installed inside a Venv in Pycharm. It specifically calls for:

`numpy==1.16.0`
`tensorflow==1.12.1`
`scipy==1.2.0`
`networkx==2.2`

Previous lines in `setup.sh` run perfectly fine in terms of updating files included in the folder. Another question I have is in general on how to setup a python package. I am currently using Pycharm CE 2020 and I've attempted creating a python package inside of my workspace. I noticed that it auto generates a **init**.py file. How can I integrate my downloads from GitHub into my Pycharm Project?

Comment: So install `pip`

Comment: I have installed pip. I have also installed all packages within Pycharm and on my Windows Computer

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to run `setup.sh` as root because it is just supposed to install some packages which do not necessitates Sudo access. You can simply create a virtual environment and run `setup.sh`. For setting up environment just run:

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 myenv    # Create an environment
$ source myenv/bin/activate              # Load the environment
(myenv) $ ./setup.sh
```

Once the environment is ready, you should be able to run the code. You can make Pycharm use that environment for executing the code.

Comment: It seems that after running `evaluate.sh`, the code runs into an error surrounding tf.contrib specifically in line 407 of `conf_gcn.py`. 

File "conf_gcn.py", line 407, in __init__
    else:               self.regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(scale=self.p.l2)
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

Comment: How would I avoid this error? Also, how can I save my virtual environment to Pycharm? In my shell, it displays a virtual environment, but I am unable to find the file path to the environment on my PC.

Comment: Tensorflow developers keep changing its interface. So you need to download the correct version.

Comment: Alright, my main question now is how I can I make pycharm use the virtual environment I generated?

Comment: There should be some way. I don't use pycharm but I believe it should be possible. Check online.